# Spotify get size of a playlist for android

Tags: android, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API to play a Spotify playlist on my app. I'd like to find the number of tracks in the playlist, but can't find anything in the docs to give me this....

Comment: Are you using the Web API or the Android SDK?

Comment: using Android SDK